# Regex to match first word until first space not containg numbers in UTF8 string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

To find first word until first space i use regex:

```
([^\s]+)
```

But how to find first word until first space not containg numbers

For example string is:

- > First12word50 Secųond-Word Thirdųword ' result must be Secųond-Word
- > First1-2word50 Secųond/Word Thirdųword ' result must be Secųond/Word
- > First1/2word50 Secųond+Word Thirdųword ' result must be Secųond+Word
- > First1/2word50 Secųond1+Word Thirdų-word ' result must be Thirdų-word
- > First1/2word50 Sec1ųond1+Word Thirdų-word ' result must be Thirdų-word
- > First1/2word50 Sec1ųond1+Word Thir11dų-word ' result must be EMPTY

Regex `([^\s(?<!\d)$]+)`

return me only

> First

Comment: What is the programming language/regex flavor?

Comment: it is `php` and `pcre`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:(?=\S*\d)\S+(?:\s+(?=\S*\d)\S+)*\W*)?\K\S*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT8mS0/1)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:(?=\S*\d)\S+(?:\s+(?=\S*\d)\S+)*\W*)?` - one or zero occurrence (i.e. it is optional) of...

  - `(?=\S*\d)\S+` - one or more characters other than whitespace that should contain at least one digit
  - `(?:\s+(?=\S*\d)\S+)*` - zero or more sequences of...

    - `\s+` - one or more whitespace characters
    - `(?=\S*\d)\S+` - ibid.
  - `\W*` - zero or more non-word characters
- `\K` - omitting the whole text in the buffer matched so far
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace characters

[PHP code](https://ideone.com/EdZ3Cx):

```
$re = '~^(?:(?=\S*\d)\S+(?:\s+(?=\S*\d)\S+)*\W*)?\K\S*~u'; 
$arr = array("First12word50 Secųond-Word Thirdųword", "First1-2word50 Secųond/Word Thirdųword",
        "First1/2word50 Secųond+Word Thirdųword", "First1/2word50 Secųond1+Word Thirdų-word",
        "First1/2word50 Sec1ųond1+Word Thir11dų-word"); 
foreach ($arr as $s) {
    preg_match($re, $s, $m);
    echo '"' . $m[0] . "\"\n";
}
```

Comment: As for UTF characters, please specify what regex flavor you are using. That is a programming language/flavor specific requirement missing in the question. BTW, `Second-Word` is matched in `First1-2word50 Second-Word Thirdword` and it *is working* as per the question requirements - there are no digits inside.

Comment: Please add your test cases to the question so that your question can be answered.

Comment: Please check if [`^(?=\S*\d)\S+(?:\W+(?=\S*\d)\S+)*\W*(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fO7wU7/3) works as expected. The value is in Group 1. Or a PCRE variation with `\K`: [`^(?=\S*\d)\S+(?:\W+(?=\S*\d)\S+)*\W*\K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/fO7wU7/4).

Comment: Yep something as expected but if no matches i need to return empty result not last char  https://regex101.com/r/jD1lA9/6

Comment: That site only accepts JavaScript regex flavor. That is why regex questions must always be tagged with appropriate programming language tag and that is why I asked you about the language you are using.

Comment: For javascript it will be differ one?

Comment: Yes, you will have to use a capturing group instead of `\K`. And you will not be able to handle Unicode that way. However, it looks working with your samples: [`^(?:(?=\S*\d)\S+(?:\s+(?=\S*\d)\S+)*\W*)?(\S*)`](https://regex101.com/r/bG9gJ0/1).

Comment: Ok thank you very much, i will try to understand what is capturing group (((

Comment: For an engine that does not support lookaheads, the only workaround is to use capturing groups. You can try using [`^(\S*\d\S*(\s+\S*\d\S*)*\W*)?(\S*)`](https://regex101.com/r/aO9fW7/1) and access the third capturing group value. If the third group is not set, then there is no valid match, you will have to assing an empty string to the result manually then.